# Build a basic authentication for rest api in node.js

Tags: node.js, basic-authentication

```
var auth = "116asd1f2341dfas2f"
//this is executed always before somone calls a request
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
var header=req.headers['authorization'];      // get the header
if(header != auth)
{
  res.status(401)        // HTTP status 404: NotFound
    .send('401 Unauthorized');
  return
}
next();
});
```

Is this a safe way to protect an API? I am new to node.js

Comment: "Safe" against what? What clients are making requests to this server? Is the traffic going over a public network? How is that auth token handled elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

**No, absolutely not.** You have written a basic middleware that might offer some protection but isn't remotely secure.

There are a lot of things that go into ensuring the protection of an API. I would suggest you learn more about **middlewares**, **token-based** authentication and how does it work (JWT AUTHENTICATION is quite popular with node.js), Passport Authentication strategies etc.

We can't write the code for you but can surely guide you to correct way of doing things. There are a lot of excellent tutorials out there that can surely help you.

Remember, doing it yourself is the only way to learn.

Comment: Why it is not secure? Do you have any explanations?